# Nim `Warning: re is deprecated`, what to use instead?

Tags: regex, deprecated, nim-lang, deprecation-warning

I'm writing a Nim program using regexes, which works fine, except that when I compile, I get this error message:

```
Warning: re is deprecated [Deprecated]
```

I've looked in the documentation for the `re` module, but there's no mention of a new way to create regexes.

My question is, if the  `re"regex"` constructor is deprecated, what *should* I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](http://nim-lang.org/docs/re.html):

> Consider using the `nre` or `pegs` modules instead.

[`pegs`](http://nim-lang.org/docs/pegs.html) is supposed to be more powerful than regular expressions and as such uses a different syntax from most regular expression engines; by contrast, [`nre`](https://github.com/flaviut/nre) is just a better wrapper around the PCRE library than `re`.

Comment: Thanks, `nre` worked perfectly and `pegs` look very interesting, I'll look into learning it.